# Failed to initialize JPA File Must Exist Error In Kubernetes

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to run an application with two different datasources. One of the datasource is to **write** one of them is to **read**

My application runs smoothly on my local. Not a single error. But when I deploy it to the k8s cluster, I am getting this error.

## Log from K8S

```
Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: File must exist : /proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/1/cwd/proc/self/task/7/cwd/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_autocorking
```

I literally have no clue. The logs below is from my local. I think its related with JPA EntityManagerFactory so I believe it worth to share.

## Log from Local

```
Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    persistence provider classname: null
    classloader: org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@8bd1b6a
    excludeUnlistedClasses: true
    JTA datasource: null
    Non JTA datasource: HikariDataSource (null)
    Transaction type: RESOURCE_LOCAL
    PU root URL: file:/Users/berkin.akaydin/IdeaProjects/sendingmethods-api/target/sendingmethods-api-XXX.XXX.jar
    Shared Cache Mode: UNSPECIFIED
    Validation Mode: AUTO
    Jar files URLs []
    Managed classes names [
        com.berkin.sendingmethodsapi.domain.connection.persistance.model.write.OrderEntity
        com.berkin.sendingmethodsapi.domain.connection.persistance.model.write.TbbLogEntity
        com.berkin.sendingmethodsapi.domain.connection.persistance.model.write.WriteConnectionEntity
        ]
    Mapping files names []
    Properties []
]
```

## Read Configuration (the same for write)

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = ["com.berkin.sendingmethodsapi.domain.connection.persistance.repository.read"],
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "readEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "readTransactionManager"
)
class readConfiguration {

    @Bean("readDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.read")
    fun readDataSourceProperties() = DataSourceProperties()

    @Bean("readDataSource")
    fun readDataSource(
        @Qualifier("readDataSourceProperties") readDataSourceProperties: DataSourceProperties
    ): DataSource =
        readDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build()

    @Bean("readTransactionManager")
    fun readTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("readEntityManagerFactory") readEntityManagerFactory: LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
    ) = readEntityManagerFactory.`object`?.let { JpaTransactionManager(it) }

    @Bean("readEntityManagerFactory")
    fun readEntityManagerFactory(
        @Qualifier("readDataSource") dataSource: DataSource
    ): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
        val entityManagerFactory = LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean()
        entityManagerFactory.dataSource = dataSource
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.berkin.sendingmethodsapi.domain.connection.persistance.model.read")
        entityManagerFactory.persistenceProvider = HibernatePersistenceProvider()
        entityManagerFactory.jpaVendorAdapter = HibernateJpaVendorAdapter()
        return entityManagerFactory
    }
}
```

## application.properties

```
jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    hibernate.ddl-auto: validate
    database: MySQL
```

## Dockerfile

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine as builder
ARG JAR_FILE=*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract

FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine
COPY --from=builder dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

Edit:
Full log is here
https://pastebin.com/smhGekNb

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace of your error in k8s.

Comment: here is the full log https://pastebin.com/smhGekNb

Comment: Hibernate seems to be looking for your entities in strange paths. I think you should check your Docker file, how your java process is started, with which options, what's the classpath etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @SebPerp. Any comment worth too much for me. I'll do

Comment: No pb. Add the pièces of information I  mentioned in your question (docker file etc). It should help to find the root cause and the solution.

Comment: @SebPerp I added the dockerfile

Comment: @SebPerp problem is fixed. I wrote the solution below

Comment: Good news ! Thanks for your docker file I didnt know about this layout management provided by spring boot

Comment: so its win-win for both of us then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem.

I don't know the exact cause of the problem but here is the solution. I want to thank @SebPerb because of his suggestion.

When I use `WORKDIR`, the problem is fixed.

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR application
ARG JAR_FILE=*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract

FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=builder application/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/application/ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```